# how to implement titanium-urban airship push notifications for android

Tags: notifications, push, titanium, urbanairship.com

I am new to titanium and want to implement push notification in titanium for android. I got to know that possibly it could be attain by using google c2dm or by urban airship. But do not know how? Google c2dm is not recommended as it only work for v2. of android. So I want to dug up using urban airship. **Could any one help me to implement push notification for android using titanium via urban airship?** I am stuck on it in my app as urban airship website is not providing any assistance to implement it in titanium. Please any any support will be highly welcomed.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We have a guide for doing push notifications with Urban Airship [on our doc site](http://developer.appcelerator.com/guides/en/push_notifications.html).

Comment: For GCM I created a module on the Marketplace, if you're interested: https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/3998?929935069

Comment: [Here is the link: using the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20101101085958/http://blog.urbanairship.com/blog/2010/05/26/appcelerator-and-urban-airship/)